# How to create and add a populated folder to a local git branch

Tags: git

So I did the typical checkout -b mybranch remote/development

then I modified some existing files
then I added a folder and some files in that folder

when it was time to commit the above changes/additions, i did a

```
git add newFolderName
git commit -m "blah" newFolderName
```

(note that I had not done an "add" or "commit" for the files in the new folder)

doing the above seemed to commit the new folder as well as (unexpectedly) the files in the new folder
The commit was pushed ok, the pull request worked, and the code was reviewed and comments were tracke in BitBucket

After making a few mods after the code review I did a
git status

It shows the new folder as being tracked, but git seems unware of the files in that folder
doing a "cd" into that folder and then a "git status" shows that the files are "untracked"

So how are they untracked if they were successfully pushed???

Was my approach for adding the folder/files wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: `as well as (unexpectedly) the files in the new folder` - actually git _only_ tracks files, not folders so there's a misunderstanding here. Can you please edit the question to show (not describe) what you are seeing (`I did a git status`, `shows that the files are "untracked"`) also indicating what branch you are on when these commands are run.

Comment: There's one possibility here for a submodule, but I would need to see actual `git status` output (or the result of `git ls-files --stage`) to be sure.

Answer (score 1):

First, I always do a `git status` before a commit: that way, I am aware of all the files (or the lack thereof) which are about to be committed.
As commented, adding a folder would add the (non-ignored) files by default.

> It shows the new folder as being tracked, but git seems unware of the files in that folder

Beside a submodule (which would manifest in a separate `.gitmodules` file in the parent repository), one possible explanation is a nested git repository (meaning a `.git/` directory in your added subfolder). Make sure this is not the case.